# Proper way to handle unique NULL value

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'm using the following model :

```
class FoodPlanningOnDemand(models.Model):
    catspad = models.ForeignKey('Catspad', null=False, blank=False)
    cat = models.ForeignKey('Cat', null=True, blank=True),
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=5)
    food_limit = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('catspad', 'cat'))
```

The `cat` field is some kind of special, since if `null` it means the planning concerns all the cats. And since I don't want a planning to be a duplicate, I don't want the `null` value to be unique too. But Django/Postgres doesn't treat `null` as a value and therefore doesn't trigger the duplicate error.

How can I manage to change this? Should I create another field?
I'm running out of ideas, thanks for your help.

Comment: null is not a value in postgres - it is `NOT VALUE` value, so just assign "not_a_cat" like NaN or any other "same not defined value" value?..

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you think a NullableBoolean can do it?

Comment: postgres `boolean` has two values - 0/1 :)

Comment: waht I meant - create classifier. like 1 is one type of cats, 2 is second type of cats and 3 is all other cats

Comment: Couldn't I use a `NullableBoolean` `all_cats` that's unique by `catspad` and set to True when `cat` is `null`?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but you can have plenty (catspad, NULL) pairs - all nulls are treated as not same - not a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, `NULL` is not a value

> When an index is declared unique, multiple table rows with equal
>   indexed values are not allowed. Null values are not considered equal.
>   A multicolumn unique index will only reject cases where all indexed
>   columns are equal in multiple rows.

ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/indexes-unique.html

If this is not what you want, you need to create a unique cat that can be identified as all cats, for example:

```
all_cats = Cat.objects.create(name='__allcats__', ....)
```

You can then either make a note of it's primary key or compare the name field to `__allcats__` to identify if the `FoodPlanningOnDemand` is applicable to all cats or a single cat.

You can do the same for CatsPad

Comment: Thanks for this, I used another method, but this one's fine too. The problem is that it creates an abstract db object.